# Writing an array of a custom object to a csv file in c# (UWP)

Tags: c#, csv, uwp

I have a list of objects, which has a couple of attributes too, and in my UWP app you should be able to download is as csv, with each object a different row and each attribute separated with a comma.
When searching similar problems I seem to find mostly outdated solutions that don't seem to work anymore.

```
public class GebruikerFormulier
{
    public int GebruikerFormulierId { get; set; }

    public string Voornaam { get; set; }

    public string Achternaam { get; set; }

    public string Geboortedatum { get; set; }

    public string Straat { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Telnr { get; set; }

    public string Campus { get; set; }

    public string Richting { get; set; }
}
```

It's a list of the object GebruikerFormulier that I need to be able to download as a csv

Comment: Can you provide an example of Base class object?

Comment: I edited my question with the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i did for a project of mine.

Created a base class that will return CSV String with quotes.

```
public class CSVClass
{
    public static string AsString(string text)
    {
        return "\"" + text + "\"";
    }
}
```

Then I inherited this class to all my classes that i needed CSV string + Overwrote `.ToString()` to return CSV Based string. In your case like below

```
public class GebruikerFormulier : CSVClass
{
    public int GebruikerFormulierId { get; set; }
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Geboortedatum { get; set; }
    public string Straat { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Telnr { get; set; }
    public string Campus { get; set; }
    public string Richting { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GebruikerFormulierId.ToString() + "," +
                            AsString(Voornaam) + "," +
                            AsString(Achternaam) + "," +
                            AsString(Geboortedatum) + "," +
                            AsString(Straat) + "," +
                            AsString(Email) + "," +
                            Telnr + "," +
                            AsString(Campus) + "," +
                            AsString(Richting) + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Now all you need is a StringBuilder to append all this as single string. Like below.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(GebruikerFormulier item in data)   //Here data is `List<GebruikerFormulier>`
{
    stringBuilder.Append(item.ToString());
}
```

Your `stringBuilder.ToString()` will return full `CSV`.